# Restrict schema changes so that I cannot delete/update tables or columns in the database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

We need to update the database so that we we can not update the database with destructive changes. We do not want to delete tables, columns or update columns. We are using entity framework for our .NET project.

How would we go about doing this?

Comment: You should do this with SQL Server permissions on the user that your application uses to connect to the database.

Comment: Can you kindly provide an example?

Comment: I don't think it's fair of you to ask Blorgbeard to type up an example of something that's so readily-available on Google and in the SQL Server documentation. That's a case where you read the documentation, try it, and then come back to Stack Overflow with an example of what you tried, and what the symptoms were when it didn't work.

Comment: If you are only providing access to the database via EF, your users won't be able to execute destructive commands unless you provide those types of commands via the application. EF uses parameterised SQL which prevents the possibility of injection of unauthorised SQL commands.

Comment: Also take care of your initializer if this is code first: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx